# Tomcat 8 doesn't enforce SSL mutual auth

Tags: ssl, tomcat8

For some reason on one of my servers, SSL with mutual auth is not enforced.
The same server.xml config on another server does end up enforcing it.

So I am reaching out to you guys, do you know why this server.xml configuration allows the user to access the page WITHOUT asking for an SSL client certificate?

```
 <Connector port="8444" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
       sslImplementationName="org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEImplementation"
    server="Apache" maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
    keystoreFile="path-to-server-ssl-keystore" keystorePass="hidden"
    clientAut="true" sslProtocol="TLS" truststoreFile="path-to-truststore" truststorePass="hidden"/>
```

My trustore contains only one Certificate (I ensured that to make sure my testing was valid), and my HMTL client is NOT configure with this certificate.

When I reach to https://URL:8444/webappname/foo.html, it works!
As you can see in the wireshark trace below, the server is not asking for the client certificate.

[image: wireshark traces of unenforced SSL mutual auth]

On the other servers, I see the server asking for a Client certificate, as shown here:

[image: wireshark traces of enforced SSL mutual auth]

At the moment I am simply trying to ensure the mutual auth is enforced so I am expecting to see an SSL error.

Any input would be welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: `clientAuth` needs an h at the end

Comment: Damn I hate it when I loose so much time for a missing letter !! Thanks a lot Dave.